# Text Wrap not being applied to stroke style in InDesign CS5

Tags: adobe-indesign, cs5

[image]

My designer supplied me a design and it contained a stroke style.

On his version (on the left), the images with a text wrap stop the stroke style.  But on my version (on the right), although I have a text wrap which cuts into text, it does not stop the stroke style (dots) that goes to the edge of the text box.  It goes underneath the image and out the other side.

You can see in the image on the left the handle stops by the text wrap.  On the right it continues through past the picture Touching it.  Apologies for bluring out most of the picture, I wasn't sure the client would like it.

I have ensured text wrap is not being ignored by the text box.  The text wrap is applied identically on both pictures.  For now I have put a white box in place to cheat it but I'd like to know the real answer.

Comment: It's hard to tell without having the document at hand. Maybe the image on the right side is pasted inside the text frame as an *anchored object*? They can only affect text which comes *after* the image in the text frame. Or the image lies behind the text frame and *Preferences > Composition > Text Wrap only Affects Text Beneath* is checked?

Comment: But surely if that was not checked hen neither would work as it's a global preference

Comment: Well if the image on the left side was *above* the text frame and the right side image was *below*, then it should react that way. (I might be missing something because of the blurred image :-))

Comment: The image on the right the Stoke style goes be rather the image. This the image on both sides is above the text frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't ask me why but paragraph rules are **not** affected by text wrap if wrapping doesn't not run up to the edge of the column.

Just increase text wrap right offset value in order to reach or extend the text frame (or column)

[image]

Comment: Woah! Trying this now

Comment: My god man.  You are right!!!!  What on earth!